# Publish a android library with classifier

Tags: android, gradle, publish

I want to publish an android studio library with aar file type.

Now it can publish but i want to add a classifier but no idea how to do.

Thanks

I should make changes in libraryVariants.all or handle in the publish task?

Thanks.

```
publishing {
    publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        artifact file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-${project.version}.aar")
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, I have several questions on the build process.

Which task will create the aar, so that i can mention the classifier there?

Answer (score 3):

The `packageLibrary` task is responsible for creating the AAR archive. You can set the classifier there. For example:

```
android {
    libraryVariants.all {
        packageLibrary.classifier = 'foo'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.

Would you mind telling me how to set?

it gives me the following error.
`Could not find method packageLibrary() for arguments`

Comment: it doesn't work even put in the android closure or sth like this 
`android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.packageLibrary {
        classifier 'aar'
    }
}`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The android plugin does not expose the packageLibrary task in such a way as you can pass it a configuration closure. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: thanks for your reply..it works, but it laters on move to the publish part. it will create the aar file with classifier aar. However the pom.xml is still incorrect.

It will be great if you know how to use maven-publish to publish android library with classifier. THanks a lot.
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact ("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-${project.version}.aar")
        }
    }
}

Comment: You should be able to specify the classifier on the publication artifact `artifact("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-${project.version}.aar") { classifier = 'foo' }`

Comment: thanks for your help.
The artifact file does not exist: 'android/build/outputs/aar/device-android-2.3.0.aar'...

i have changed to artifact with additional classififer but the pom classifier is missing and the aar is not published.

Do you have any suggestions for publish android library with classifier?

Comment: My only other thought would be to remove the classifier from the `packageLibrary` task and specify it only in the publishing configuration.